# Haskell Wreq - Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Exts.Item a0’

Tags: haskell, wreq

I'm experiencing a type error when I run the following code:

```
runPost :: IO String
runPost = do
    res <- post "http://httpbin.org/post" ["num" := (31337 :: Int)]
    return $ show res
```

The error is the following:

```
• Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Exts.Item a0’
                  with actual type ‘FormParam’
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: "num" := (31337 :: Int)
      In the second argument of ‘post’, namely
        ‘["num" := (31337 :: Int)]’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        res <- post "http://httpbin.org/post" ["num" := (31337 :: Int)]
```

When I inspect the type of `:=` in ghci, I see what appears to be the correct type:

```
*Main Network.Wreq> :t (:=)
(:=)
  :: FormValue v =>
     Data.ByteString.Internal.ByteString -> v -> FormParam
```

What I'm wondering is why `GHC.Exts.Item` is appearing as the expect type when I run the compiler. I've only imported the functions I'm using from `Network.Wreq`. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's clear (to the compiler, if not to your fellow human) that `("num" := (31337 :: Int)) :: FormParam`. What isn't clear to the compiler (and which you need to help it decide on) is the type of `[x]` once `x` is known to be a `FormParam`.

The `Item` "type" is actually a type family, coming from the [`IsList`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.15.0.0/docs/GHC-Exts.html#t:IsList) class; and the `IsList` connection is coming from having the `OverloadedLists` extension turned on.

Comment: Thank you for the concise explanation. I was able to get the following to compile with `OverloadedLists` enabled (as it was in defaults):
`[("num" := (31337 :: Int))] :: [FormParam]`.

After disabling `OverloadedLists`, my original code compiled.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a minimal program that causes basically the same error, which should make it more clear what's going on:

```
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedLists #-}

main :: IO ()
main = print [True]
```

```
    • Couldn't match expected type ‘GHC.Exts.Item a0’
                  with actual type ‘Bool’
      The type variable ‘a0’ is ambiguous
    • In the expression: True
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely ‘[True]’
      In the expression: print [True]
  |
4 | main = print [True]
  |               ^^^^
```

The `print` function has type `Show a => a -> IO ()`. If the `OverloadedLists` extension weren't enabled, then the expression `[True]` would have type `[Bool]`, and everything would be fine. But with the `OverloadedLists` extension enabled, the expression `[True]` instead has type `(GHC.Exts.IsList l, GHC.Exts.Item l ~ Bool) => l`. After unifying, `print [True]` ends up basically having type `(Show a, GHC.Exts.IsList a, GHC.Exts.Item a ~ Bool) => IO ()`. Notice that the type variable `a` doesn't appear anywhere to the right of the `=>`, which makes that an ambiguous type. To make the ambiguity even more concrete, note that in addition to `[Bool]`, the type `NonEmpty Bool` would also work for `a` there. The compiler doesn't know which one you want and doesn't want to guess, so it gives you that error. To solve the problem, add a type annotation, like this: `main = print ([True] :: [Bool])`

For the actual problem in your question, the only differences are that you have the `Postable` typeclass instead of `Show`, and the `FormParam` type instead of `Bool`. You can fix your problem by replacing the erroring line with `res <- post "http://httpbin.org/post" (["num" := (31337 :: Int)] :: [FormParam])`.